# Charts/Graphs in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, graph, charts, dashboard

I'm developing a dashboard app where I need several different charts/graphs. Is there any way that I can create them without any library? And if so, can you teach me how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are [many existing charting/graphing solutions](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chart) that are open source. Even if you do not want to use one, you could still examine the source code to see how they are implemented. Beyond that, please be **very specific** about what you need, as you are asking far too broad of a question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn how to use a chart properly I suggest you to watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhKtbECeazQ&ab_channel=ChiragKachhadiya).
After that you can start something with live data and/or github arsenal implementations. But first start with the fundamentals. Hope that answered your question also.